# How to update if statement in views through AJAX in Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my app I have votable posts where you vote through AJAX which works fine but I want to update status of the post (whether it is agreed milestone) upon voting through AJAX as well. Status partial:

_milestone.html.erb

```
 <% if post.agreed? %> Agreed Milestone <% elsif post.milestone? %> 
 Proposed Milestone <% end %>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @post }
    format.js
    @post.upvote_by current_user
  end
  if @post.votes_for.up.size == count_users
      @post.toggle! :agreed
  end
end
```

upvote.js.erb

```
$('#voting-<%= @post.id %>').hide();
$('#agreed-<%= @post.id %>').html("<%= j render(partial: 'posts/agreed',
locals: {post: @post}) %>");
$('#milestone-<%= @post.id %>').html("<%= j render(partial: 'posts/milestone',
locals: {post: @post}) %>");
```

Agreed partial is list of voters.

So when post reaches certain number of votes it changes its boolean agreed to true. I want to then update status in views. I tried rendering milestone element as partial and several other approaches but the if statement is never executed and status does not update.

Comment: You should add the upvote.js.erb to your question so we have a clearer idea of how you are updating your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to update it before rendering the view,

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @post.upvote_by current_user
  if @post.votes_for.up.size == count_users
      @post.toggle! :agreed
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @post }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great it helped. Thank you. I exported milestone as partial and modified controller as you suggested. I added last line to my upvote.js,erb.